# MySQL delete a record based on unix epoch timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table as follows:

```
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| id       | firstName           | lastName        | tstamp        |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 133      | James               | Mosher          | 1593612000000 |  
| 145      | Bill                | Turner          | 1593698400000 | 
| 146      | Jeremy              | Vine            | 1593784800000 |  
| 152      | Ramon               | Jesus           | 1593180000000 |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

and I wanted to be able to DELETE records based on the **tstamp** value (which is epoch unix time) IF they are **OLDER** than **x days**. I am using the query below which should **only** **DELETE** the **last row** (Ramon Jesus) as it is **older than 5 days**... however, it deletes ALL of the records. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

`DELETE FROM students WHERE tstamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamps contain milliseconds which you must remove prior to the comparison, because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns a `DATETIME` value without milliseconds.
Also the comparison must use the opposite inequality operator:

```
DELETE FROM students 
WHERE tstamp / 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY));
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ezUNT7mD7JxA3isrrN9uDo/1).
Results:

```
| id  | firstName | lastName | tstamp        |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ------------- |
| 133 | James     | Mosher   | 1593612000000 |
| 145 | Bill      | Turner   | 1593698400000 |
| 146 | Jeremy    | Vine     | 1593784800000 |
```